# React Native - How to display first label fully and hide second label when it is < certain width?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

I have two views with texts inside, acting like labels. These labels are put inside a card view with a fixed width. **I want the first label to always be fully visible regardless of length of text, as much as possible.**

To achieve this, the second label should be shortened as much as possible with `Ellipsis Mode` and `FlexShrink` but once the second label is shortened such that its width is < 25 px, I want to hide it.

[image]

**What I've tried:**

1. The method I have right now is to read the width of the second label using `onTextLayout` and hide accordingly, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to achieve this effect, hopefully purely with styling.
2. I have also tried `TextWrap` then hiding the second row but it wraps as long as both tags exceed the width - I want the second label to shorten as much as possible first, before wrapping.

**Current Code Setup**

```
const [showLabel, setShowLabel] = React.useState(true);

...

return (
    <View style={styles.tagsContainer}>
        {labels.slice(0, 2).map((tag: string, index: number) => {
            if (index === 1 && !showLabel) {
                return;
            }

            return (
                <View
                    key={index}
                    style={[styles.tagWrapper,{flexShrink: index,}]}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={styles.tag}
                        numberOfLines={1}
                        onTextLayout={(e) => {
                            if (index === 1 && e.nativeEvent.lines[0].width < 17) {
                                setShowLabel(false);
                            }
                        }}
                    >
                        {tag}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            );
        })}
    </View>;
)

const TAG_HEIGHT = 15
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tagsContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        minHeight: TAG_HEIGHT,
      },
    tagWrapper: {
        minHeight: TAG_HEIGHT,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        marginRight: 4,
        paddingHorizontal: 2,
      },
    tag: {
        ...font(10, 'regular'),
        lineHeight: 14,
    },
})
```

*ps. Does using useState make this component stateful? That's probably not encouraged?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong about your current solution. There are other ways:

- conditionally render the second View based on the width of the outer View. You can measure the width using the outer View's onLayout prop: `onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => setWidth(nativeEvent.layout.width)}`
- measure the width the same way, but set the size of your `.slice` instead based on the result

Yes, using useState makes the component stateful, but there's nothing bad about that. State is a good tool to hold local data like this.

Comment: i see what you mean. Could using onLayout/onTextLayout cause weird behaviour if the text is dynamic?

Comment: Either one will fire every time the text changes. In practice this should be fine - unless the text is changing many times per second, it shouldn't hit your performance too badly. React's diffing should prevent updates unless something actually changes.